# Common internet file system

Tags: android

CIFS is common internet file system, which is a protocol used to access windows file system . I want to access windows file system through my android phone. The Windows operating system acts as CIFS Server. So i have write a program for CIFS client and run it on my android phone, so that i can access windows file system. I have to write that program in java to run it on Android phone. So my problem is how to get started, packages that are necessary to implement it, classes i need to use and so on..So does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at the [Samba](http://www.samba.org/) project [jcifs](http://jcifs.samba.org/)?:

> JCIFS is an Open Source client library that implements the CIFS/SMB
>   networking protocol in 100% Java. CIFS is the standard file sharing
>   protocol on the Microsoft Windows platform (e.g. Map Network Drive
>   ...). This client is used extensively in production on large
>   Intranets.

Comment: ya. But its highly technical. I want a simple solution. I want to establish a connection between my phone and computer. After the connection is open, it should be possible for me to transfer files between computer and mobile phone. Then i have to close the connection. I want to know about the basic functions of java that are necessary to implement the above situation.